# How to disable cookieless URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, cookies, cookieless

I'm using cookies on my ASP.NET MVC site.
Recently I've noticed that there are many pages */(X(1)S(ofezdiyg5ae5veyvmylvjkgd))/***

shown in Google and Yandex.
I've investigated and found out that they are pages with cookieless authorization.
I turned cookieless off in my Web.config.
Now my site requires cookies to operate.

But neverthess these pages are still working and have code 200.

I want to stop them working - and redirecting to normal pages.

How can I do that?